# Empty Pi Hat/Bonnet

Tags: hardware, electronics, hat

Does anyone know where to find a Pi Hat or Bonnet that is *empty*?  By that I mean a PCB that has the connectors to solder stackable headers onto, but no connections just raw PCB?  The reason I want this is that I have a non-hat module I want to add to my Pi, but it would be more convenient if I could glue it to a platform and then solder it on.

Specifically, I am trying to add a [buck converter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B076H3XHXP) to the Pi, but as far as I'm aware it isn't available in a convenient Hat.

Comment: This may be a good place to start https://www.adafruit.com/product/2314

Comment: @SteveRobillard - That's close but not quite.  I'm worried that the conductive pads on the PCB will accidentally connect something on the bottom of my board.  That's why I want a completely blank PCB.  I can't mount another module on the board you are suggesting.

Comment: Why not just hot glue some standoffs to separate the board and buck converter?